# Howto automatically load text from txt file to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows, visual-studio, text

I have a small program I use to launch applications (Visual Studios), I would like to add a Label that would (AUTOMATICALLY) display a message from a text.txt file once the application is load (NO BUTTONS). I will have about 10 of these small apps so this would make it easier to update in the future.I am new to program.

Comment: TextBox.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("text.txt").Substring(0,1000)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this

```
Label1.Text = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Test.txt")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you double-click your Form window in Visual Studio, you will create an event handler function called `FormName_Loaded` or similar. This function will be automatically called (no buttons required) when the form finishes loading.

In this function, you can set the value of your label text. For example, if your label is called `lblFileData`, you can put in:

```
lblFileData.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("path\to\file\text.txt")
```

This loads all text from the file and assigns the text to the label. Just make sure that the label size and max length are sufficient to show all the text in the file.

Comment: I tried this and no luck, Please keep in mind I'm new to this.

Public Class Form1
    Form1_Loaded
    label1.Text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Gamer\Desktop\Launchers\test.txt")


End Class

Answer (score 0):

What metacubed suggested should work. Assuming the label was added through the designer. The code behind should look like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  Try
    Label1.Text = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\testFile.txt")
  Catch ex As Exception
    HandleException(ex)
  End Try
End Sub
```

Helpful tip, you should always use a Try/Catch block when reading from files. Otherwise if an exception occurs, your application will crash and that's not user friendly. The "HandleException()" is just a method I made up that can do certain actions when exceptions occur such as displaying the text "Unable to read from file." on the Label1.